# Yii2 GridView sorting by count(*) from another table

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My app has these tables:

- article(include `category_id` column references to `category(id)`)
- category

It outputs gridview:

```
<?=
  GridView::widget([
    ...
    'columns' => [
       ...
        [
            'label' => 'Article count',
            'attribute' => 'articles',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return count($model->articles);

            },
        ],
        ...
    ],
  ])
?>
```

I want to make sorting by articles count. How can I do this?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, dont get the count value directly in view, get it from Model who's admin u r sorting

for that use criteria =>    $criteria = new CdbCriteria();

Provide your count var in Model to csort() 
like

```
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->defaultOrder = 'id DESC';
$sort->attributes = array(
                                'articles'=>array(
                                    'asc'=>'c.articles ASC',
                                    'desc'=>'c.articles DESC',
                                ),
                                '*',
    );
```

then provide that $sort variable to ActiveDataProvider

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort' => $sort,

    ));
```

Comment: The question is about Yii2, not 1